# DB: store selected options (including none), with null pointing to a default option

Tags: database-design, json

My web users can choose among zero, one or more services (i.e. selectable with checkboxes). The choices should default to only `service1`.

The list of possible services is available via REST API. It could expand/change over time.

In a DB, I need to store the users choices (json format). But ideally, a "null record" there would mean the default. Order doesn't matter. Some service options would be stored too.

The problem with a simple object (dictionary)

```
a = {
   service2: { someOptions }
}
```

is that the default `{}` or null/undefined means no service selected.

Is there a clever way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply store the user's selections. That is, null=nothing selected. It is a bit unclear to me why you say:

> ideally, a "null record" there would mean the default

The required extra storage space seems comparatively small. Also, consider what you want to happen if, in the future, you decide that `service1` is no longer the default, but instead your new fancy `service5`? Do you want switch to happen for old users too?

Comment: ah, good point on changing default.